# How can I make a link to a node obtained from an SQL query?

Tags: nodes, database

I'm trying to make a module for a users profile page which shows all of the content of certain types they have created. I have got the query to work and list the results in a block - however I can not get the returned list to contain links to the nodes. Here is my code:

```
function get_articles()
{
  if(arg(0) == 'user' && is_numeric(arg(1)))
  {
    $account = user_load(arg(1));
  }

  $result = db_query('SELECT node.title FROM {node} node WHERE (( (node.uid = :uid) AND (node.status = \'1\') AND (node.type IN (\'article\')) )) ORDER BY `created` DESC LIMIT 5', array(':uid' => $account->uid));

  if($result->rowCount() > 0)
  {
    $list = array(
      '#theme' => 'links',
      '#links' => array(),
    );

    foreach($result as $record)
    {
      $list['#links'][] = array('title' => $record->title, 'href' => $account->name . '/' . $node->title);
    }

    return drupal_render($list);
  }
  else
  {
    return t('This user has no Articles.');
  }
}
```

Thank you in advance to anybody who answers.

Comment: Could you not just make a view?

Comment: I tried using Views but I couldn't figure out how to make it only show the viewed users content - also I'm a bit of a coding noob and this has been quite a good coding exercise for me :)

Comment: Fixed it, needed to change:

    $node->title

into:

    $record->title

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
foreach($result as $record)
{
  $list['#links'][] = array('title' => $record->title, 'href' => $account->name . '/' . $node->title);
}
```

You have $node->title in this code, but there is no $node object.  The href appears to be the user's name, and then the title of a node?  So the link would be http://example.com/johndoe/My Page Title, which doesn't seem right.

Is this what you're trying to do?  First, add node.nid to your list of SQL columns

```
foreach($result as $record)
{
  $list['#links'][] = array('title' => $record->title, 'href' => 'node/' . $record->nid);
}
```

You might also look into bypassing the $list array, and the drupal_render() function, and simply use:

```
$links = "<ul>";

foreach($result as $record)
{
  $links .= "<li>" . l($record->title,'node/'.$record->nid) . "</li>";
}

$links .= "</ul>";

return $links;
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this works just as I wanted it to - I thought drupal_render() was the preferred way in Drupal 7?

Comment: drupal_render() exposes the object to the theme engine, so custom themes and modules can tweak the way it looks.  Definitely not a bad idea to use it, but it's not always necessary.